# Testing of a RegisterFile in Chisel

Tags: scala, chisel

I want to test a vector of registers (a registerFile). Below is a function which reads the indexed value of a registerFile:-

```
class ViewRegFile(regnum: Int, size: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val registers =  Input(Reg(Vec(regnum,UInt(size.W))))
    val inputs = Input(UInt(size.W))
    val ok = Input(UInt(1.W))
    val values = Output(UInt(size.W))
  })
  val buffer = RegInit(VecInit(Seq.fill(regnum)(0.U(size.W)))) // so we have a reset to buffer regmap
  when(io.ok === 1.U){
  for(i<-0 until regnum) {
  buffer(i)  := io.registers(i)
  }
  }
  val itr = io.inputs
  io.values := buffer(itr)
}
```

The above code takes the registerFile *registers*, which has *regnum* registers of size *size*. I am indexing the registerFile using variable *inputs* and output the indexed value of the registerFile through the variable *values*.

To test the functionality I created a registerFile in a testbench, initialized some values to the File and wanted to the read the outputs out using the above written function *ViewRegFile*. I am stuck now as to where could I have gone wrong in the implementation. Below is the testbench I tried making:-

```
import java.io.File
import chisel3._   //needed to declare testbench (tb) registerFile
import chisel3.iotesters
import chisel3.iotesters.{ChiselFlatSpec, Driver, PeekPokeTester}

class RegUnitTester(c: ViewRegFile, val regnum: Int, val size:Int) extends PeekPokeTester(c) {
 private val mod = c
val register = RegInit(VecInit(Seq.fill(regnum)(0.U(size.W)))) // tb registerFile
val val1 = 1434.U(size.W)
val val2 = 9082.U(size.W)
register(1) := val1
register(2) := val2 
poke(mod.io.registers, register) //loaded tb registerFile to function registerFile
for(j<- 0 until regnum) {
  poke(mod.io.inputs, j) //desired values from function registerFile
  poke(mod.io.ok,1)
  step(1)
  poke(mod.io.ok,0)
  peek(mod.io.values) } // indexed output
}

object RegTester extends App {
  println("Testing RegFile Viewer")
  iotesters.Driver.execute(Array("--target-dir", "generated", "--generate-vcd-output", "on"), () => new ViewRegFile(4, 16)) {
    c => new RegUnitTester(c,4,16)
  }
}
```

and *poke* is failing with the error :

```
[error] overloaded method value poke with alternatives: 
[error]   (signal: chisel3.Aggregate,value: IndexedSeq[BigInt])Unit <and>
[error]   (signal: chisel3.Bundle,map: Map[String,BigInt])Unit <and>
[error]   [T <: chisel3.Element](signal: T, value: Long)(implicit evidence$10: chisel3.iotesters.Pokeable[T])Unit <and>
[error]   [T <: chisel3.Element](signal: T, value: Int)(implicit evidence$9: chisel3.iotesters.Pokeable[T])Unit <and>
[error]   [T <: chisel3.Element](signal: T, value: BigInt)(implicit evidence$8: chisel3.iotesters.Pokeable[T])Unit <and>
[error]   (path: String,value: Long)Unit <and>
[error]   (path: String,value: Int)Unit <and>
[error]   (path: String,value: BigInt)Unit
[error] poke(mod.io.registers, register)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using Chisel constructs in your Tester. The Chisel API calls (including `RegInit`, `VecInit`, `.U`, and `.W`) are intended for constructing hardware; in testers you should use pure Scala to model the behavior. For example:

```scala
import java.io.File
import chisel3._   //needed to declare testbench (tb) registerFile
import chisel3.iotesters
import chisel3.iotesters.{ChiselFlatSpec, Driver, PeekPokeTester}

class RegUnitTester(c: ViewRegFile, val regnum: Int, val size:Int) extends PeekPokeTester(c) {
  private val mod = c
  val register = Array.fill(regnum)(BigInt(0)) // Using BigInt because Int is 32-bit
  register(1) = 1434 // I didn't wrap in BigInt because Scala will convert from Int automatically
  register(2) = 9082 // If you create values that don't fit in 32-bit *signed* Int, wrap in BigInt(...)
  // You can't poke internal values, there is some support for this, see:
  // https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Chisel-Memories#loading-memories-in-simulation
  //poke(mod.io.registers, register) //loaded tb registerFile to function registerFile
  for(j<- 0 until regnum) {
    poke(mod.io.inputs, j) //desired values from function registerFile
    poke(mod.io.ok,1)
    step(1)
    poke(mod.io.ok,0)
    peek(mod.io.values) // indexed output
  }
}

object RegTester extends App {
  println("Testing RegFile Viewer")
  iotesters.Driver.execute(Array("--target-dir", "generated", "--generate-vcd-output", "on"), () => new ViewRegFile(4, 16)) {
    c => new RegUnitTester(c,4,16)
  }
}
```